# 401 unauthorized error before trying to get access token in spring security oauth 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am getting 401 unauthorized error before trying to get access token in spring security oauth2.

I have both server (authorization and resource server) and client applications. Those applications created by using sparklr2 and tonr2 applications.

I have bypassed login form at both applications. It means that it doesn't ask username and password at the beginning or both appkications, I used custom classes and setting user roles as "ROLE_USER" for both applications.

This is my error stack trace:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/Client] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."] with root cause org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:243)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:556)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:514)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:479)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:136)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:198)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:505)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:472)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
at com.sebit.security.client.oauth2.controller.HelloController.welcomePage(HelloController.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my web.xml at my server application:

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my spring-servlet.xml at server side:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>



<http pattern="/index/**" create-session="never" 
    entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="ROLE_USER, SCOPE_READ" />

    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<http auto-config="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    >
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <!--intercept-url pattern="/index/**" access="ROLE_USER" /-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
    <anonymous />
</http>

<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.sebit.security.server.oauth2.controller.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="Authorization" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
    class="com.sebit.security.server.oauth2.controller.PreAuthentication">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
</beans:bean>


<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    >
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="Authorization" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="myClient" resource-ids="Authorization" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write" secret="secret"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>

<beans:bean id="accessConfirmationController" class="com.sebit.security.server.oauth2.controller.AccessConfirmationController">
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
```

This is my web.xml at client side:

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my spring-security.xml at client side:

```
    <http auto-config="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
    <anonymous/>
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>   

<oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.sebit.security.client.oauth2.controller.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="messages" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
    class="com.sebit.security.client.oauth2.controller.PreAuthentication">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<oauth:resource id="Authorization" type="authorization_code"
    client-id="myClient" client-secret="secret" access-token-uri="http://localhost/Authorization/oauth/token"
    user-authorization-uri="http://localhost/Authorization/oauth/authorize" scope="read,write" />    

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="converters">
        <beans:set>
            <beans:bean class="com.sebit.security.client.oauth2.controller.AccessTokenRequestConverter" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="helloController" class="com.sebit.security.client.oauth2.controller.HelloController">
    <beans:property name="restTemplate">
        <oauth:rest-template resource="Authorization" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

This is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet at client side:

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

After I call

"/Client/index"

it successfully bypasses login forms (at server and client side) and it succesfully calls

"/Authorization/oauth/authorize"

It successfully add client_id, response_type, scope, redirect_uri and state parameters.

Access is confirmed and approval page come. After I clicked on "Authorize" button, I get 401 unauthorized error.

Any helps greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is the 401 coming from? The token endpoint (it looks like it has some funny authentication filters, so maybe)? If you could pinpoint that in the server logs that would certainly help (enable DEBUG logging in org.springframework.security if you haven't already).

Comment: @DaveSyer yes problem is coming from token endpoint, I debugged the code, it succesfully implement /oauth/authorize. But when try to request /outh/token, 401 unauthorized error appears.

Comment: Can you explain why you configured the token endpoint security the way you did then.

Comment: @DaveSyer I am new to spring-security-oauth2, So that's why it is normal to see a funny configuration :). I was inspired from sparklr2 and tonr2 applications and then created both server and client aplications. Could you show me a better way to configure token endpoint?.

Comment: @DaveSyer All I want to do is bypassing login forms at both client and server applications without asking username/password, getting access token and finally getting a string message. I was trying to get a String message from /index map (I could find a better mapname :)). I binded resource to the HelloController (I could find a better controller name). In controller in /index map it requests "http://localhost/Authorization/oauth/authorize" by using OAuth2RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's up to you to decide how to do authentication. But note that the /token endpoint is not (in standard auth code flows anyway) consumed by users. It should have security appropriate to its consumers (client apps), so if I were you I would start by removing the "preAuthFilter" (how would it be able to authenticate a client?). If you don't think clients ought to have secrets you are probably not writing an enterprise or web grade product, but you are free to secure that /token endpoint any way you like. Just be aware that it will be getting Basic authentication headers from the client (if the client is a standard tonr-style Spring Security app).